# Facebook mobile browser and cookies

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I have problem that facebook mobile browser (open website from facebook) does not remember cookies (Android and iPhone).

I'm setting cookie like this:

```
setcookie('acceptEntrance', true, time() + strtotime("1 year"), "/");
```

but after page reload cookie isn't present. Have sameone idea how to solve it ?

Goal:

I have a website which requires accept ToS. On a first visitor visit i show a form to accept them. When visitor submit form (GET) i set a cookie (code above), but cookie isn't present. This problem is just when i open website from facebook link (Android and iPhone) - in case i open website in regular browser everything works fine (mobile/desktop)